# Make array of objects from array of strings

Tags: ruby, jruby

I have an array of strings read from file.

```
contents = File.readlines('foo.txt')
```

I can create an some object with string

```
my_foo = Foo.new("some_text")
```

I need to make an array of objects `Foo` made by array of strings `contents`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be worth to mention, that `File.readlines` will read everything into memory, what may cause memory issues with large files. Consider using this code:

```
File.foreach('foo.txt').map do |line|
  Foo.new(line)
end
```

It read file line by line, almost as fast as your code, but more secure.

Comment: why not `foos = File.foreach('foo.txt').map { |line| Foo.new(line) }` rather than declaring the `Array` and pushing into it?

Comment: @engineersmnky you are right, map is better. updated

Answer (score 3):

Is this what your looking for?

`contents.map {|i| Foo.new i}`